# codeigniter with visual studio code - How to lookup translation strings while coding

Tags: codeigniter, visual-studio-code

I'm developing with Visual Studio Code a codeigniter project and there are several parts across the code that reference strings defined inside the application/language/ folder for each translation.

Currently when I encounter something like `echo lang("ctn_1")` I have no idea what the ctn_1 string says so I need to open the language definition file and look for `$lang['ctn_1'] = "Email Address";`

I imagine there is a better way (wishing for a plugin in that lets me just hover over `lang("ctn_1")` and shows "Email Address" as a tool tip).

Any advice on how to make me more efficient around this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and further your question falls under the "off-topic" area.

Comment: sorry, not intended to be off-topic. unsure where this would be a valid question.

Comment: Even though its an off-topic question but i'm not sure if that is supported in any `text-editor` out their or even in an `ide` that i know and i've never seen anything like that before in any video tutorial .. have you seen it before?